# ie prevent mousewheel while mouse is over a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i prevent the mouse wheel from scrolling the entire html page which im over a div which can mousewheel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [jquery mousewheel extension](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/mousewheel):

```
$('#my_div').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I have and works fine in everything but IE where my mouse wheel scrolls the entire page not just the div?

Comment: @user520300. sorry, can't say anything about IE support.

Answer (score 0):

Or without JQuery you can use the native event [mousewheel](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/onmousewheel.shtml) and call `preventDefault`.

I personally haven't tested this.